# Performing an if statement in a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I want a variable which contains an if statement, doing this in WordPress but cannot seem to get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
<?php $priceperpost= {
   if ( $linecount > 15) 
{ 
   echo "109";
}
elseif ($linecount > 30) {
   echo "89";
}
elseif ($linecount > 100) {
   echo "Please Call";
}
else {
   echo "129";
}  
}
?>
```

Comment: If the `$linecount` is > 100 it will never reach the `echo` line because it is already hit on the first `if`.

Comment: And you cannot assign code blocks to variables. You need to read up on statements and expressions.

Comment: Any thing greater than 100 is also greater than 15 and 30! order in descending order.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to do one-line if statements; you'll have to nest them to get the effect you want.  Basically in this code, if x is equal to 1, then $value gets assigned the value 2.  Otherwise it gets the value 3.

```
$x = 1;
$value = ($x == 1 ? 2 : 3);
echo $value;
```

Outputs: 2

It is equivalent to:

```
$x = 1;
if ($x == 1) {
    $value = 2;
} else {
    $value = 3;
}
echo $value;
```

Comment: Nested statements with ternary operators are not really a very good idea when it comes to readability.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are trying to assign that value rather than directly output onto the screen:

```
<?php
  $priceperpost = "129"; // default
  if ($linecount > 100) {
    $priceperpost = "Please call"; // highest price break value first
  } elseif ($linecount > 30) {
    $priceperpost = "89";
  } elseif ($linecount > 15) {
    $priceperpost = "109"; // lowest price break value last
  }
 ?>
```

Or something a bit more compact and flexible - you can store the values in a file or databse and generate the array from that data rather than have to write a new elseif for new price break values:

```
<?php
  $priceArray = array( // insert price break values in descending order
    100 => "Please call",
    30 => "89",
    15 => "109",
    0 => "129",
  );

  foreach ($priceArray as $breakValue => $price) {
    if ($linecount > $breakValue) {
      $priceperpost = $price;
      break; // found the price break, so we can exit the loop here
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it something like the following, because as stated only your first `if` or your `else` will be hit in the example you provided:

```
switch (true) {
    case $linecount > 100:
        $priceperpost = "Please Call";
        break;

    case $linecount > 30:
        $priceperpost = 89;
        break;

    case $linecount > 15:
        $priceperpost = 109;
        break;  

    default:
        $priceperpost = 129;
        break;
}
```

In general when there are going to be more `elseif`s it tends to get a bit hard to read. In these cases I often prefer a `switch` statement for readability (but opinions seem to differ about this).

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/UnztIT